# JPA entities PrePersist and PreRemove callbacks, are they fired only once per life time of an application?

Tags: jpa, callback, entity, listener, lifecycle

The JPA 2.0 specification talks about the `PrePersist` and `PreRemove` callbacks on page 95:

> The PrePersist and PreRemove callback methods are invoked for a given
>   entity before the respective EntityManager persist and remove
>   operations for that entity are executed. For entities to which the
>   merge operation has been applied and causes the creation of newly
>   managed instances, the PrePersist callback methods will be invoked for
>   the managed instance after the entity state has been copied to it.
>   These PrePersist and PreRemove callbacks will also be invoked on all
>   entities to which these operations are cascaded. The PrePersist and
>   PreRemove methods will always be invoked as part of the synchronous
>   persist, merge, and remove operations.

My mother tongue is not English, so I may misunderstand what would be quite clear for another dude. Or the quote could use a clarification or two. But I fail to understand:

**Will the PrePersist and PreRemove callback be called only once per life time of a running Java EE application?**

If the callbacks are fully synchronized with calls to [EntityManager#persist(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist%28java.lang.Object%29) and [EntityManager#remove(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29), then yes I expect the callbacks to be fired only once. I usually don't persist my entities more than once, nor do I delete them over and over again just for the fun of it. Alas this is "just" my reasoning.

But! Say you have code that shall persist one entity at the beginning of a new transaction, then within the same transaction you hook the entity up with some new and non persisted entities. It would be intuitive and certainly not wrong to provoke a cascading persist operation on all those relationships with a secondary smooth call to EntityManager#persist on the owning entity before the transaction commit. In that case.. **would the PrePersist callback be called again, a secondary time?**

Comment: Calling persist on a managed entity is a no-op, so it will not result in pre-persist getting called either.    Many JPA providers will allow you to call persist on a detached entity and not immediately throw an exception - in which case, prepersist will likely be called for that entity, and an exception thrown when it eventually does go to the database.  So there is the chance pre-persist will be called, but it will only be called once in a transaction that is successful.  In your senario, it depends on if the referenced entity in the tree is managed or detached.